# Assign a variable to a condition only if the condition is met using Which

Tags: conditional, code-generation

If I have a conditional of the form:

`Which[Round[b[i], 0.1] == 74,1,40 < b[i] < x,2]` where `b[i]` represents a number that gets updated in a loop and x is the variable I am asking for below.

How can I save the value of `Round[b[i], 0.1] == 74` as a variable (let's say `x` as in the code) only for when the condition `Round[b[i], 0.1] == 74` is met. So, to be more specific if `b[i]=73.99`, for example, then the code would translate to `Which[Round[73.99, 0.1] (*which is equal to 74*) == 74,1,40 < b[i] < 73.99,2]` but if `b[i]=75`, for example, then it will keep being `Which[Round[75, 0.1] == 74,1,40 < b[i] < x,2]` as `Round[b[i]]` is still not 74 and hence `x` is still a variable with nothing assigned to. Is this possible?

Edit: I will also appreciate comments on getting `Round[b[i], 0.1] == 74` equal to a variable even when the condition is not met, which should be simpler to do. For this case I tried naively `Which[x==Round[b[i], 0.1] == 74,1,40 < b[i] < x,2]` but here x will be "True" or "False" but not the number.

I hope this makes sense and I appreciate in advanced your help

Thank you!

Comment: why can't you just do `x = Round[73.99, 0.1];  If[x == 74, .etc....]` ?

Comment: What are you expecting the `Which` to evaluate to when the `x` variable is unassigned?  This feels like an [XY problem.](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using a `Which` statement to control the flow, you can do more than one thing at a time by using `;`. While it might seem like the purpose of `;` is just to suppress output, it's actually the infix form of `CompoundExpression` which lets you join many expressions together where only one overall expression is allowed.

```
Which[
  Round[b[i], 0.1] == 74,
  x = Round[b[i], 0.1]; 1, (* you could also just put x = 74 *)
  40 < b[i] < x,
  2
]
```

You could also use brackets to set the assignment apart from the comparison. I think this would allow you to complete both tasks that you wanted:

```
Which[
  (x = Round[b[i], 0.1]) == 74,
  1,
  40 < b[i] < x,
  2
]
```

This is pretty close to what you had in your edit, I think you just needed the brackets.

Comment: Thank you @MassDefect your first code using `;` (which I did not know was possible) is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @John No problem! Note that in the first code, x only gets an assignment if the first condition is met, while in the second code x always gets assigned regardless of which condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
Which[
    If[Round[b[i], 0.1] == 74, x = Round[b[i], 0.1]]; Round[b[i], 0.1] == 74, 1,
    40 < bi < x, 2  
 ]
```

You can remove the value of `x` by using `x=.`.